# dynamically select fields in linq

Tags: linq, select, dynamic

I have this here:

```
Dim query = FromTableRows.Select(Function(Row) Row.Item(_SqlSyntaxChecker.SelectedFields(0)))
```

Row is a normal DataRow, so I can get the field value of the rows like this: Row.Item(0), Row.Item(1), etc.

SelectedFields contains the field names of the FromTableRows.

Now, I would like to select all the fields in the SelectedFields list, while the number of the selected fields can vary.

Is this possible? How should I modify the code?

Thanks.

Comment: What `Type` of result are you expecting? An `IEnumerable<object[]>` (whatever the syntax is for that in VB)?

Comment: yes, right, I would like to have this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply make use of the [`ItemArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) property, if I understand your question correctly.

```
FromTableRows.Select(Function(Row) Row.ItemArray)
```

The `ItemArray` property is an `object` array that contains the elements found in the `DataRow`. You will, of course, lose any mapping via this method from columns to elements, but it sounds like that's what you want.